# Loading images from various sources in QTWebKit

Tags: html, qt, browser, webkit

I am trying to create a "smart" web browser to load local images. Basically it works as a GUI for an application. I am using QTWebKit to power the browser, the problem is that the images of a given page can be found in different places, some are local files, others are in different resource files.

For example:
an HTML node to load image x.jpg can look like `<img src="x.jpg">` and for image y.gif on the same page it can be `<img src="y.gif">`, now x.jpg is a local file that can be either in the root directory or in some other place. y.gif on the other hand can be in a resource file.

I want the web browser first to set the paths to all possible sources and once the page has been loaded or preferably while the page is loading searches for the images and loads them from their original path.

I considered the option of reading the HTML data first, parse it and search for the resources one by one, then edit the html to include the full path of the image but that would take a long time than what I want and it isn't practical.

Can any one put me on the right direction or does any one have any ideas on how such a design can be implemented.

EDIT: I have manage to delegate the requests by overriding the QNetwrokAccessManager and QNetwrokReply and been able to get the path to the image. The only problem is loading the image into view. I am currently using QHttp to handle the incoming requests but so far I haven't been able to load the image.

been trying to use QHttp's Get() function and passing the path to the jpg image as (file:///path/to/image) and also tried using the local path but nothing is working.

Comment: which OS? What is the network layer based on?

Comment: Sorry, its windows and all files are local files no network connection is required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to tell QWebPage not to load specific type of resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575245)
You need the same approach but instead of dropping request by constructing QNetworkRequest with empty QUrl you need to pass url to the file on the disk.